# Resize content of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, image-resizing, contentmode

Please check the attached images in order to understand the issue in brief.[image]

Please note the size of the X character and the circle character . The images for both the characters are equal in size , but due to the shape of the second character it appears a bit smaller. I know i can use another image for the second character but then it spoils the shape of the character . So can any one suggest me some way through which i can redraw the content of UIImage to be equal in both the image views.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIImageView` property `AspectFit` to set image content from xib, For example:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;


if (imageView.bounds.size.width > image.size.width && imageView.bounds.size.height >image.size.height) 
{
  imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Maybe some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some "small zooming" in runtime according to the image displayed, but keep your image views same sized in the xib, use

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then in the function that chooses what image to present:

```
float scale = 1.0f;
select (myImageType) 
{
   case 1: scale = 1.1f;break;
   case 2: scale = 1.162f;break;
   default: scale = 1.0f
}
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale);
..
myImageView.image = myUIimageToShow;
```